# sqlite INDEXED BY with same plan is slower

Tags: indexing, sqlite

So i have two queries, one that specifies INDEXED BY for each table in the query, and another that only specifies it for one. The EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output for both is identical minus the INDEXED BY addition in the one plan. The issue is that the fully specified query runs much slower, why would that be?

In situations when data in the DB is going to change over time and we can't run ANALYZE (should it be run periodically?) locking all the indexes down with INDEXED BY seems like a prudent idea if they all test well. Thoughts?

Comment: "Change over time" and "locking down" appear to be contradictory.

Comment: can you extend your question with the queries in question?